# GoogleBot (and malicious sites) requesting invalid directory

Tags: web-crawler, googlebot

GoogleBot is requesting valid files from an invalid directory that has never existed. For example:

```
/energy/
```

is appended to a valid path and file to produce:

```
/energy/css/example.css
```

Oddly, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` also shows a valid page in an invalid directory (in this example `http://www.example.com` is my site):

```
http://www.example.com/energy/docs/anthro/payment.php
```

`/docs/anthro/` is a valid directory but `payment.php` would never be in this directory and `/energy/` of course has never been valid.

Even more odd, malicious sites are requesting valid pages as well from `/energy/` such as:

```
/energy/register.php
```

What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing "virtual directory" with "physical directory"?  You don't state what web server you are using, but most of them provide the capability to map URLs to different locations than are strictly present on the file system.

Comment: This is an Apache web server on a shared host. I have not mapped any urls to different locations in .htaccess except to reroute invalid pages to `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

Check your robots.txt and sitemap

Comment: Nope. There is nothing with `/energy/` in either of these. No way this directory would ever have made it into these accidentally either. The first time this happened, it was a directory called `model-rockets`, I added an exclusion into robots.txt hoping to stop it. But this is the second out of no-where directory that has showed up.,..